# Client-based email encryption for standard email providers

Tags: email, encryption, client

I would like to use an established (and free) email provider like Yahoo! Mail or GMail, but I don't like them mining my emails.

So I was thinking about implementing an email client that would:
1. retrieve any new email and delete it from my Inbox
2. encrypt the email body and scramble the addresses while keeping a local index
3. put the encrypted copy back on the provider's server, in a 'Read Mail' folder for instance

Note here that I am not concerned about point-to-point encryption of emails, since emails from Amazon, my bank or my grandmother are not encrypted anyway. My concern is solely about Google for example mining decades of my email communications.

Search functions will have to be done in the client using the local index, and the encryption key could be unique for each email.

My questions are:
A. does anyone know about an existing such implementation?
B. would Google or Yahoo! disallow something like this once they catch up, given that their business model is providing a free service in exchange for our data?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any existing solution that does what you want, but I also don't see the point.

Google mines your email when it is delivered, not at some later date and once they have it, they have it. Deleting the message from the server won't remove their mined data about your emails from their internal database.

Implementing your solution would have no effect other than making it impossible for you to reply to said emails using the Gmail web client and wasting a lot of resources.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my understanding, mining requires access to the entire corpus of the data, for finding trends, correlations, etc. I don't think my emails can be 'mined' one by one, unless by mining you mean something else. If you mean Google parses my email to serve me ads, I agree. If you mean Google creates a copy of my email for later analysis, that would mean they store all my emails in duplicate which would be inefficient. Could you please clarify what do you mean by 'Google mines your email when it is delivered'?